# Losing time part while updating date column using JDBC . How can we preserve it?

Tags: java, oracle, date, jdbc

I have tried below code but after update date updated in DB is without the time I passed.

The time update is 00:00:00.

How I can update the time also in a Oracle `Date` column?

I have also tried to use `preparedStatement.SetDate`, `preparedStatement.setTime` 
also I tried `datecolumn=TO_DATE('Nov 6, 2014 12:30:00 AM', 'MON DD, YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')` but still the time part was lost.

The date update in database is `Nov 6, 2014 12:00:00 AM`.

```
Calendar startDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(startDateTime.getTimeInMillis());

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, t);

System.out.println("Update Date  "+startDateTime.getTime().toLocaleString());

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Update query :

```
 update table_bpm_step_inst 
 set wait_time=?  
 where objid = 'abc'
```

Comment: where from startDateTime is coming?

Comment: The column data type for this table column allows time?

Comment: How are you checking the value, directly or also through JDBC? Are you able to set a time manually - are you sure there isn't a trigger setting it to midnight, for example, and you aren't trunc'ing it when querying? The code you show and the `to_date` version should both work so something else seems to be happening.

Comment: If you are checking the value directly what are your NLS session parameters?

Comment: Sezin : StartdateTime can be any date value .
Uwe : Yes
Alex : I am checking from SQL Developer . It shows time if I use "sysdate" to update time but from JDBC it shows date and 00:00:00

Comment: Maybe adding `updateQuery` to the question will show something important, but your `to_date` version looks fine anyway. And there's definitely no trigger, and an update with `sysdate` or `systimestamp` retains the time, not just a fresh insert? (What is the column data type?)

Comment: What is the query used? How are you checking the result? For example Oracle SQL developer by default only renders the date part, not time when querying `date` columns.